# R- help reading fixed-width format

Tags: r, import

could you please help me read this file in R:

```
 Weekly SST data starts week centered on 3Jan1990

                Nino1+2      Nino3        Nino34        Nino4
 Week          SST SSTA     SST SSTA     SST SSTA     SST SSTA
 03JAN1990     23.4-0.4     25.1-0.3     26.6 0.1     28.6 0.5
 10JAN1990     23.4-0.8     25.2-0.3     26.6 0.1     28.6 0.5
 17JAN1990     24.2-0.3     25.3-0.3     26.5-0.1     28.6 0.5
 24JAN1990     24.4-0.4     25.5-0.4     26.5-0.1     28.4 0.3
 31JAN1990     25.1-0.1     25.8-0.2     26.7 0.1     28.4 0.3
 07FEB1990     25.8 0.2     26.1-0.1     26.8 0.2     28.4 0.4
 14FEB1990     25.9 0.0     26.4 0.0     26.9 0.2     28.5 0.5
 21FEB1990     26.1 0.0     26.7 0.2     27.1 0.3     28.9 0.8
```

As you can see, below each NinoXX header, there are two data columns with SST and SSTA.

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: It's about the 1990–1995 El Niño-Southern Oscillation Event. SSTA stands for sea surface temperature anomalies; SSA stands for sea surface temperature. You can read about the scales [here](https://www.science.smith.edu/geosciences/ocean/lab_pages/El_Nino_Web/temp_exercise.htm). The data is temperature and anomalies scaled value in each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kludgy hack. It would be far better to ask the originating author(s) to provide a better format.

```r
dat <- read.fwf(textConnection("
                Nino1+2      Nino3        Nino34        Nino4
 Week          SST SSTA     SST SSTA     SST SSTA     SST SSTA
 03JAN1990     23.4-0.4     25.1-0.3     26.6 0.1     28.6 0.5
 10JAN1990     23.4-0.8     25.2-0.3     26.6 0.1     28.6 0.5
 17JAN1990     24.2-0.3     25.3-0.3     26.5-0.1     28.6 0.5
 24JAN1990     24.4-0.4     25.5-0.4     26.5-0.1     28.4 0.3
 31JAN1990     25.1-0.1     25.8-0.2     26.7 0.1     28.4 0.3
 07FEB1990     25.8 0.2     26.1-0.1     26.8 0.2     28.4 0.4
 14FEB1990     25.9 0.0     26.4 0.0     26.9 0.2     28.5 0.5
 21FEB1990     26.1 0.0     26.7 0.2     27.1 0.3     28.9 0.8"), c(15, 4,9, 4,9, 4,9, 4,4), skip = 2)
colnms <- trimws(unlist(dat[1,], use.names = FALSE))
colnms <- paste0(colnms, ave(as.character(colnms), colnms, FUN = function(z) if (length(z) == 1) "" else seq_along(z)))
dat <- data.frame(lapply(setNames(dat[-1,], colnms), type.convert, as.is = TRUE))
dat
#              Week SST1 SSTA1 SST2 SSTA2 SST3 SSTA3 SST4 SSTA4
# 1  03JAN1990      23.4  -0.4 25.1  -0.3 26.6   0.1 28.6   0.5
# 2  10JAN1990      23.4  -0.8 25.2  -0.3 26.6   0.1 28.6   0.5
# 3  17JAN1990      24.2  -0.3 25.3  -0.3 26.5  -0.1 28.6   0.5
# 4  24JAN1990      24.4  -0.4 25.5  -0.4 26.5  -0.1 28.4   0.3
# 5  31JAN1990      25.1  -0.1 25.8  -0.2 26.7   0.1 28.4   0.3
# 6  07FEB1990      25.8   0.2 26.1  -0.1 26.8   0.2 28.4   0.4
# 7  14FEB1990      25.9   0.0 26.4   0.0 26.9   0.2 28.5   0.5
# 8  21FEB1990      26.1   0.0 26.7   0.2 27.1   0.3 28.9   0.8
```

If you have a file instead of just the text, you would use something like this for your first step.

```r
dat <- read.fwf(filepath, c(15, 4,9, 4,9, 4,9, 4, 4), skip = 1)
```

Walk-through:

- The widths (`c(15, 4,9, ...)`) were determined manually, nothing magical here. (Minor sub-note: I paired them visually as `15`, then `4,9`, etc; that is not a comma-decimal notation, it is merely showing visually that the `4` and `9` are logically assigned together; R ignores this and treats this as `c(15, 4, 9, 4, 9, ...)`.)
- `skip=2` in the first code block is half aesthetic (for the answer), half functional. That is, my first code block has a newline after the opening quote, and while `read.table` will silently skip that, `read.fwf` will not, so I have to set `skip=1` to skip that. Since I also want to skip the `Nino*` line, I have to increment to `skip=2`. For production and a real file to read from, you should use `skip=1`.

If you want to programmatically preserve the Nino number, then perhaps

```r
ninos <- trimws(unlist(read.fwf(textConnection("
                Nino1+2      Nino3        Nino34        Nino4
 Week          SST SSTA     SST SSTA     SST SSTA     SST SSTA"), c(15, 13, 13, 13, 8), skip = 1)[1,], use.names = FALSE))
ninos <- ninos[nzchar(ninos)]
colnames(dat)[-1] <- paste0(rep(ninos, each = 2), "_", colnms[-1])
dat
#              Week Nino1+2_SST1 Nino1+2_SSTA1 Nino3_SST2 Nino3_SSTA2 Nino34_SST3 Nino34_SSTA3 Nino4_SST4 Nino4_SSTA4
# 1  03JAN1990              23.4          -0.4       25.1        -0.3        26.6          0.1       28.6         0.5
# 2  10JAN1990              23.4          -0.8       25.2        -0.3        26.6          0.1       28.6         0.5
# 3  17JAN1990              24.2          -0.3       25.3        -0.3        26.5         -0.1       28.6         0.5
# 4  24JAN1990              24.4          -0.4       25.5        -0.4        26.5         -0.1       28.4         0.3
# 5  31JAN1990              25.1          -0.1       25.8        -0.2        26.7          0.1       28.4         0.3
# 6  07FEB1990              25.8           0.2       26.1        -0.1        26.8          0.2       28.4         0.4
# 7  14FEB1990              25.9           0.0       26.4         0.0        26.9          0.2       28.5         0.5
# 8  21FEB1990              26.1           0.0       26.7         0.2        27.1          0.3       28.9         0.8
```

Note that these names are generally not R-friendly, so you'll need backticks with many of them, e.g.,

```r
dat$`Nino1+2_SST1`
# [1] 23.4 23.4 24.2 24.4 25.1 25.8 25.9 26.1
```

That can be remedied in any number of ways, over to you.